# Is there a way to add a data-attribute to codemirror line?

Tags: javascript, html, codemirror

Is there a way to add data-attribute and add more info in a CodeMirror line?

something like that:

`<pre class="CodeMirror-line" data-line-info="line-info" role="presentation"></pre>`

Thank you